# Save filter criteria on a SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have a Products table as follows:

```
create table dbo.Product ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null,
  Price decimal not null
)
```

I am creating Baskets (lists of products) as follows:

```
create table dbo.Baskets ( 
  Id int not null
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
)

create table dbo.BasketProducts ( 
  BasketId int not null,
  ProductId int not null,
)
```

A basket is created based on a Search Criteria using parameters:

1. MinimumPrice;
2. MaximumPrice;
3. Categories (can be zero to many);
4. MinimumWarrantyPeriod

I need to save these parameters so later I know how the basket was created.

In the future I will have more parameters so I see 2 options:

1. Add MinimumPrice, MaximumPrice and MinimumWarrantyPeriod as columns to Basket table and add a BasketCategories and Categories tables to relate a Basket to Categories.
2. Create a more flexible design using a Parameters table:

   create table dbo.BasketParameters ( 
     BasketId int not null,
     ParameterTypeId int not null,
     Value nvarchar (400) not null
   )

   create table dbo.ParameterType ( 
     Id int not null
     Name nvarchar (80) not null
   )

Parameter types are MinimumPrice, MaximumPrice, Categories, MinimumWarrantyPeriod, etc.

So for each Basket I have a list of BasketParameters, all different, having each on value. Later if I need for parameter types I add them to the ParameterType table ...

The application will be responsible for using each Basket Parameters to build the Basket ... I will have, for example, a Categories table but will be decoupled from the BasketParameters.

Does this make sense? Which approach would you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is superior (especially since you are using a relational data store. I.e. SQL Server), since it is properly referential. This will be much easier to maintain and query as well as far more performant.

Your second solution is equivalent to an EVA table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Which are usually a terrible idea (and if you need that type of flexibility you should probably use a Document Database or other NoSQL Solution instead). The only benefit to this is if you need to add/remove attributes regularly or based on other criteria.

Comment: Actually EAV is an incredibly powerful solution when done correctly. I have used it many times as an extension to more standard relational data with great success. That being said, EAV can be used incorrectly and it is truly horrible.

Comment: @SeanLange Indeed it can be very useful in certain scenarios, however it sounds like OPs data is fairly well structured, static and not liable to change 'too much', hence I would greatly prefer first solution

Comment: I really dislike the first solution of adding new columns for each type of filter. Especially given that the OP states that the filters are going to change. That would require adding/removing columns from the table and all the queries that touch it every time the filter options change. Kind of defeats the point of relational data.

Comment: @SeanLarge, yes but he will have to edit the application to actually add the filters in the first place! And will be changing the queries to the database to USE the data that he stores. So he will already be modifying it. Best to keep each version well defined, instead of losing filters between versio. I would only prefer this if, for instance - the user could define new filters themselves or something. It just opens up too many problems using a dynamic solution like this in my opinion (orphaned records, queries that are hard to read/troubleshoot, performance issues if it scales up too much).

Comment: And this is exactly why I voted to close this question as being primarily opinion based. Maybe the application would allow the user to change the available filters, then you don't need a code change at all. This is not at all uncommon and properly designed is not a performance issue at all.

Comment: Fair doos - I would see more information required for proper answer rather than actually opinion based but yeah I see your point!